# Fill a substring array with zeroes

Tags: arrays, c, hex

I am trying to convert a decimal into one hexadecimal `char` array of 8 characters in a format like this:

```
    //input
    float longitude = 3335;
    //output
    char longitude = "00000d07";
```

I need to convert the decimal input to hexadecimal and at the same time fill the array with zeroes if it hex value isn't of 8 characters

to do so, I wrote this function:

```
void hex_to_decimal_int_function(uint32_t decimalnum, char buffer_hex_int[8]) {
    long quotient, remainder;
    int i, j = 0;
    char hexadecimalnum[100];
    quotient = decimalnum;

    // Convert decimal to hexadecimal
    while (quotient != 0) {
        remainder = quotient % 16;
        if (remainder < 10)
            hexadecimalnum[j++] = 48 + remainder;
        else
            hexadecimalnum[j++] = 55 + remainder;
        quotient = quotient / 16;
    }

    // reverse the array
    hexadecimalnum[8] = '\0';
    int b = strlen(hexadecimalnum);
    int z = b - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        hexadecimalnum[i] ^= hexadecimalnum[z];
        hexadecimalnum[z] ^= hexadecimalnum[i];
        hexadecimalnum[i] ^= hexadecimalnum[z];
        z--;
    }
       
    // Fill the 8bits array with zeroes at the left

    char hex[8];//hexadecimal value, conversion result, max = 8 letters 0Xffffffff
    char *text = hexadecimalnum;
    strncpy(hex, &text[0], 8);    
    hex[8] = '\0';
   
    int a = strlen(hex);        
    if (decimalnum == 0) {
        sprintf(buffer_hex_int,"00000000");
    } else {
        switch (a) {  //fill the hex array with zeroes
          case 1:
            //char filling_zeros[7] = "0000000";
            sprintf(buffer_hex_int, "0000000%s", hex);
            break;

          case 2:
            //char filling_zeros[6] = "000000";
            sprintf(buffer_hex_int, "000000%s", hex);
            break;

          case 3:
            //char filling_zeros[5] = "00000";
            sprintf(buffer_hex_int, "00000%s", hex);
            break;

          case 4:
            //char filling_zeros[4] = "0000";
            sprintf(buffer_hex_int, "0000%s", hex);
            break;

          case 5:
            //char filling_zeros[3] = "000";
            sprintf(buffer_hex_int, "000%s", hex);
            break;

          case 6:
            //char filling_zeros[2] = "00";
            sprintf(buffer_hex_int, "00%s", hex);
            break;

          case 7:
            //char filling_zeros[1] = "0";
            sprintf(buffer_hex_int, "0%s", hex);
            break;

          default://strlen(hex) = 8==> just copy the original hex value
            sprintf(buffer_hex_int, "%s", hexadecimalnum);
        }
    }      
}

int main() {
    float longitude = 3335.593750;
    uint32_t decimal = longitude;
    hex_to_decimal_int_function(decimal, buffer_hex_int);

    printf("buffer_hex_int : %s", buffer_hex_int);
    return 0;
}
```

the function works fine when I use it on VScode and GCC, but when I try to use it on other compiler like CUBDEIDE, it shows meaningless symbols instead of zeroes.

something like this:

```
 input_decimal = 737;
 output_hexadecimal= 0$qy2E1;
```

Where I could have gone wrong with my code?

Comment: Why don't you use just `sprintf("%08X", ...)`?

Comment: `char hex[8];  hex[8] = '\0';` isn’t right.

Comment: sprintf("%08X", ...) actually this one worked fine, thanks. I didn't know that sprintf supports hex values.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior for multiple reasons:

- the initial loop may store fewer than 8 characters into `hexadecimalnum` and `hexadecimalnum[8] = '\0';` sets the null terminator beyond the last character set by the loop, leaving indeterminate contents in between as the array is uninitialized.
- `hex[8] = '\0';` writes beyond the end of the `hex` array.
- `strncpy(hex, &text[0], 8);` would not make `hex` a proper C string if `text` has 8 or more characters.

You can substantially simplify the code by making the loop iterate 8 times and storing the characters from offset 7 down to 0:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void hex_to_decimal_int_function(uint32_t decimalnum, char *buffer_hex_int) {
    // Convert decimal to hexadecimal
    int i = 8;
    while (i --> 0) {
        buffer_hex_int[i] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[decimalnum % 16];
        decimalnum /= 16;
    }
    buffer_hex_int[8] = '\0';
}
```

Note that you can also use `snprintf` for this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void hex_to_decimal_int_function(uint32_t decimalnum, char *buffer_hex_int) {
    snprintf(buffer_hex_int, 9, "%08"PRIX32, decimalnum);
}
```